# Replacing XML file at runtime on android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm new to android development and I was wondering if it is possible to change an XML file during runtime of the application.
I'm having an XML file with data that I put into a database, but I would like to have the possibility to download another XML-file (with newer data) and replace the old one.
(I'm not talking about the manifest.xml file or layout.xml files, it's a file I created myself in a self-made subfolder)

Any suggestions how I can manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download `XML`, parse it in the database. Why do you need to 'replace' it? (You can do this but it's not the best solution).

What you should do is download the `XML` into memory (for example `HttpClient` or any other), parse the `XML` and directly insert into the database.

This means you don't need to save anything.

Comment: I would like to have the data offline available at all times, and only sync the data when the user wants to.
Does this work the way you say, or is the data released after closing the app?

Comment: If you store it in the database locally (like you say you are doing) then it is offline. (the database will still be there after closing the app)